# Include Storyboard or xib files in Cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, storyboard, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am creating a Cordova plugin for a ionic application. I want to add a design part in the plugin for the iOS application. 
Can I add a storyboard or Xib from the Cordova plugin itself?

For the source files and assets of iOS platform we can configure it in the plugin.xml file in the iOS section. 
For ex: `source-file` or `asset` tags

But can we use the Xib or Storyboard from the plugin in the Ionic project?

If yes under what key should we add it in the plugin.xml section? Assets section or any other different key is used for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `xib` files using `resource-file` in `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
  <resource-file src="path/to/your.xib" />
</platform>
```

Comment: As it's for a plugin, better add it in the `plugin.xml`

Comment: After adding .xib path in plugin.xml, how to show that .xib file, OnClick() from .html file?'

Comment: @McDonal_11 you would need to call into Cordova using cordova exec and then handle the command in a Cordova plugin and load the xib (plenty of examples of that last part on SO)